# Is it possible to navigate to page from native code onFlutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to navigate to my inbox page when clicking the notification. I handle notification on native code. I want to do this when clicking the notification. `Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/inboxPage')`

**Android Native**

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

**IOS Native**

```
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = userInfo["title"] as! String
    notificationContent.body = userInfo["body"] as! String
    notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID.init().uuidString, content: notificationContent, trigger: nil)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error: Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print("error \(theError)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes totally possible

Comment: Yes you can create your own platform channel and do it

Answer (score 0):

define a global var for a listener function

```
Function kNotificationClicked;
```

instantiate/init a **method channel**

```
  const platform = MethodChannel('com.myapp.etc');
  platform.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
    if (call.method.compareTo('notification-clicked') == 0) {
      if(kNotificationClicked!=null){
       kNotificationClicked(call.arguments);
     }
    }
  });
```

in any widget (mostly while init or even better while the app init) set the callback

```
kNotificationClicked = (args){
  //go to the route
}
```

on native side(kotlin) instantiate a method channel

```
    private val CHANNEL = "com.myapp.etc"
    protected lateinit var platform: MethodChannel;

    fun configureFEngine() {
        platform = MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL)
        platform.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        }
    }
```

invoke when you wish

```
   fun notificationClicked() {
        platform.invokeMethod("notification-clicked", args)
    }
```

I've not tested the code, but have shown you how would i approach this